# Prove that the four roots of unity form an abelian multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

My question is:

> Let $i =  \sqrt{-1}$. Prove that the four roots of unity $\{1, -1, i, -i\}$ form an abelian multiplicative group.

I know that abelian group is a group with commutative property. But I'm not sure how to prove this one. I tried searching through few websites like Wikipedia, YouTube and etc, but couldn't find anything helpful. Can someone please help?

Please forgive my English and structure of the question, I'm new here! :)

Comment: What is it you are having trouble proving? You just need to check that the properties hold for these four elements.

Comment: Did you, ever in your life, prove that any set with a given operation is a group? I bet you did. Now simply follow the same steps.

Comment: Also, defining $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$ is nonsense. $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined for $\mathbb{R}^+$. You should define $i$ as one of the solutions of $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question. But I'm having hard time making the multiplication table for this. What should I add for the axis of the table? Should I simply add the element as is and multiply with each other or should I take the fourth root or something?

Comment: @5xum I was just figuring out how to ask the question man. I'm from Sri Lanka and my mother tongue is not English. So there is that. Hope you can understand. :)

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu see http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/group-theory/group-tables.html

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu A multiplication table **always** has the elements of the set on it's "axes".

Comment: @godonichia That link has an answer to my exact question. Thanks a ton!
5xum and all others, Thank you very much for helping me. You guys are the best! :)

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu is this for MPZ5140 TMA1 at OUSL? :D I was also searching for the same and found the answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that the product of two elements of the set $\{\pm1,\pm i\}$ is again an element of the set (*). You need to show that the reciprocal of an element of the set is again an element of the set. You don’t need to check commutativity or associativity, because you’re dealing with complex numbers under multiplication, and those conditions are always satisfied.

(*) The “two elements” above may be equal, too.

Answer (score 0):

Write out the multiplication table for this set and then use it to verify that every group axiom is satisfied.

Comment: Note that this approach could take *ages* since associativity is not straightforward from the table.

Comment: I suppose I was assuming familiarity with $\mathbb{C}$ as a group, thereby implying that the associativity axiom is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $G$ is an abelian group, then $T_n = \{ g 
\in G : g^n=1 \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Indeed, if $G$ is abelian, then $x \mapsto x^n$ is an endomorphism of $G$ whose kernel is $T_n$.

In your case, $G=\mathbb C^\times$ and $n=4$.