# Is it possible to see from Cayley table that group is cyclic or what are the generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Few days ago, I found a problem that you can use Cayley table to see group is cyclic. I also use this site but I did clear about it. As they state that any element just below the identity element in row is generator. But when I take group of fourth root of unity then it is not true. So please give me what is actual idea ?

Comment: I know all about it. But question is different. Is it possible to check every cyclic group by Cayley table. I take this example to explain. So please tell me about it.

Comment: "As they state that any element just below the identity element in row is generator." No, this is wrong - as you noted yourself. But of course you can see from the Cayley table that the group is cyclic. You only need to find one element $a$, a generator, such that the Cayley table fits for $a^0,a^1,a^2,\ldots ,a^{n-1}$. In your example, you can take $a=i$.

Comment: Exactly.. now you clear my doubt ...but it clearly says that if it is cyclic then element present in diagonal is not generator.

Comment: You miss 3 in this group as 1 and 4 are in diagonal element so can't be generator whereas 2,3 are.

Comment: Also gcd plays a vital role here gcd(5,2)=gcd(5,3)=1. But it not make us sure that if gcd is 1 then it is generator. According to me, we can combine these two results.

Comment: No, I mean the cyclic group with $3$ elements $\{1,a,a^2\}$, where $a$ is a generator, but of course $a^2=a^{-1}$ as well. We have $a^3=1$. And $a^ 2$ is in the diagonal, but it is a generator. So the claim "but it clearly says that if it is cyclic then element present in diagonal is not generator" is again false.

Comment: In this group closer of 4.2= 3 under modulo 5 is not here

Answer (score 0):

A cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly $\phi(n)$ generators. In your case, $G=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ is a cyclic group under multiplication of order $n=4$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649026/prove-that-the-four-roots-of-unity-form-an-abelian-multiplicative-group). Hence only $\phi(4)=2$ elements are generators, i.e., $\pm i$.
Once we have found a generator, we know that the group is cyclic. This can be easily seen from the Cayley table, by reproducing the Cayley table with the powers of a generator $a^0,a^1,\ldots,a^{n-1}$, whose product is given according to the rule $a^ia^j=a^{i+j}$.